# d3 setting multiple attributes from the same function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there any way to set multiple attributes from the same function?

```
d3.selectAll('.myshape')
    .attr('y',function(d,i) { ... calculates something ... })
    .attr('height',function(d,i) { ... calculates something very similar... })
```

I would like to calculate `y1` and `y2` at the same time and then set `y = y1` and `height = y2-y1`. But the standard way of doing this in d3 seems to be having separate functions per attribute. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have an intensive calculation that you would like to compute only once *per element*, regardless the number of attributes you're setting.

That being the case, you can use an `each` to pass the current element (`this`), along with the datum, the index and the group, if you need them:

```
d3.selectAll(".myShape").each(function(d,i,n){
    //Here you put the complex calculation 
    //which will assign the values of y1 and y2.
    //This calculation runs only once per element
    d3.select(this).attr("y", y1).attr("height", y2 - y1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. But you could solve the issue in a indirect way. This adds slightly more overhead but worth it imo. JS doesn't have nice "compile-time" (as far as the js engine is concerned) macros like C family, that give you nice expansions without runtime cost.

like this (you may already know):

```
let myshape = d3.selectAll('.myshape')

['y', 'height', ...].forEach(attr => myshape.attr(attr, calcAttr));

function calcAttr(a, i) {
    // shared code

    switch (a) {
    case 'y':
        //attr specific
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that won't work, like I said they are very similar but not the same. But I guess you answered my question about whether it was possible.

Comment: you should alter the function perhaps with a `switch` or `if else` condition to handle the differences. The code that is shared can be in a shared scope.